# List of different softwares mandatory before running appium

Tags: appium

I am struggling with appium installation. Kindly list the application/software that is required before the appium installation.
Please provide me with the link list, which will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short list of software and hardware required for automating the applications using Appium:

**PC should have JDK, Appium Server, Eclipse, Android SDK installed**

Check out the [link](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/09/appium-tutorials.html) which lists all the software and steps to start Appium.

For more information regarding the installation please check it out [here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/appium-tutorial-for-beginners/)